# How to split results in MySql PHP

Tags: mysql

I am having issues with Splitting results with MySql. I am still new to MySql.

I have a table like this in MySql `products_table`

```
Id | Product | OWNER
---------------------
1  | Bag     | Admin
2  | Shoes   | Admin
3  | Shirts  | User
4  | Purse   | Admin
5  | Shoes   | User
6  | Sandals | User
7  | Watch   | Admin
8  | Jean    | User
9  | Slippers| Admin
10 | Laptop  | User
11 | Phones  | User
12 | Piano   | Admin
13 | Keyboard| User
14 | Template| Admin
15 | Desktop | Admin
```

I want a result that **brings out maximum of 10 results, at least 4 products from user and 6 products from admin in Random order**

So the result will give something like this.

```
1  | Bag     | Admin
4  | Purse   | Admin
11 | Phones  | User
14 | Template| Admin
3  | Shirts  | User
9  | Slippers| Admin
5  | Shoes   | User
8  | Jean    | User
7  | Watch   | Admin
12 | Piano   | Admin
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Maybe see UNION.

Comment: UNION? Do I need Union since its just one table @Strawberry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`UNION ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) here, to get results in two different `Select` queries, due to two different `Where` conditions:

```
(
 SELECT Id, Product, Owner 
 FROM products_table 
 WHERE Owner = 'User'
 ORDER BY RAND() 
 LIMIT 4   -- get random 4 rows for 'User'
)
UNION ALL
(
 SELECT Id, Product, Owner 
 FROM products_table 
 WHERE Owner = 'Admin'
 ORDER BY RAND() 
 LIMIT 6   -- get random 6 rows for 'Admin'
)
ORDER BY RAND() -- eventually random sorting again
```

---

If you can upgrade to latest version of MySQL (**[8.0.2 and above](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/)**), we can utilize [Window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) instead of `Union`. We will determine randomized [`Row_number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) within specific partitions for `Owner`. We can then use this result-set as a Derived Table and consider only 4 rows for User and 6 rows for Admin

```
SELECT dt.* 
FROM 
( SELECT Id, 
         Product, 
         Owner, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Owner 
                            ORDER BY RAND()) AS row_num 
) AS dt 
WHERE (dt.Owner = 'User' AND dt.row_num <= 4) OR 
      (dt.Owner = 'Admin' AND dt.row_num <= 6) 
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Let me try this @Madhur Bhaiya